# Is "i've forgotten to" possible here?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Suppose I'm on the train on my way to work and I suddenly realise I've forgotten to close my bedroom window, can I say: "I've forgotten to close my window!"? Or is past simple the only option?

Comment: You know the answer to this. We have answered these simple past/present perfect examples for you multiple times. It depends on what you want to say and your context.

Comment: I've given you context and I've told you before,  if I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310796/have-you-locked-the-door-or-did-you-lock-the-door). I'll answer there, since there's a bit more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'I have forgotten' and 'I forgot' are possible.

I would use 'I forgot...'

I remember  the window. (I closed the window and I remember this)

I forgot   the window. (I didn't close the window. I forgot this.)

Comment: I remember**ed** to close the window. I remember to close the window [every time I leave]. forgot is fine here.

Comment: I agree that both are possible, and I too would use "I forgot," but the second two examples make this answer very confusing IMO. Why introduce the examples with "remember?"